# Question about foundry testing

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to create an on chain nft with Foundry. I'm basing my project on the Cyfrin course repo. Here https://github.com/Cyfrin/foundry-nft-f23.

Except that I'm not doing the Moodnft. I decided to go with a Smart contract from another Patrick Collins project. Here https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/all-on-chain-generated-nft.

I would like to create a basic on chain svg with foundry. The contract seems to compile correctly. However when I execute a test I get an error on the 'testTokenURIIsCorrect()' function. Here's the test --https://gitlab.com/b2896/foundry-nft/-/blob/main/test/SvgNftTwoTest.t.sol

My project repo https://gitlab.com/b2896/foundry-nft/

Any ideas on writing a successful unit test?

Comment: What error are you getting and what test command are you running?